# Whilst trying to sketch a "sawtooth" function...

Tags: real-analysis

I read and understood the following definition*:

> Define
>   $$h(x)=|x|$$
>   on the interval $[-1,1]$ and extend the definition of $h$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$ by requiring that $h(x+2)=h(x)$. The result is a periodic "sawtooth" function.

However, I was then promptly asked to sketch the graph of $(1/2)h(2x)$ on $[-2,3]$ and to give a qualitative description of the functions
$$h_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}h(2^nx)$$
as $n$ gets larger.

However, this is where I am confused: Is it not the case that
$$h_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}h(2^nx)=\frac{1}{2^n}|2^nx|=\frac{2^n}{2^n}|x|=|x|,$$
and $h_n$ behaves just like $h$ regardless of the size of $n$? Either I am misunderstanding something or the book has made a typo. Could anyone clarify this for me? Thanks in advance!

*This is from Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*.

Comment: The problem is that $h(2^n x) = |2^n x|$ only when $|2^n x|\leq 1$, other wise the fact that $h(x+2) = h(x)$ part comes in and messes with it.

Comment: That would be true if $h$ were just the absolute value function, but it's not.

Comment: $h(x) = |x|$ only when $x \in [-1,1]$

Comment: Didn't mean to steal an answer from your comments.  I got up to make tea while answering and didn't refresh my browser when I came back.

Comment: What is the maximum value of $h(x)$?  What is the maximum value of $\frac{1}{2^n} h(2^n x)$?

Comment: I understand that the function looks like a sawtooth because of the periodicity, but I guess that what I truly wanted to ask is: are the graphs of, say, $h_1$, $h_5$ and $h_n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ alike? As in, exactly the same?

Comment: @JonasKibelbek, I believe I see it now.

Comment: @JosuéMolina You might be interested in [this question of mine.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107237/heuristic-iterated-construction-of-the-weierstrass-nowhere-differentiable-functi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite.  We have that $h(x)=|x|$ only for $-1\leq x\leq 1$.  Let $n=1$.  Then, for example,

$$
h_1(1)=\frac{1}{2}h(2)=\frac{1}{2}h(0)=0.
$$

This is the periodicity working.